# Found 1 low severity vulnerability Error, while creating new react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I create react project using > npx create-react-app my-app it showing me an error:

> found 1 low severity vulnerability run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details.

I tried to solve this using npm audit fix but it doesn't work.

```
                   === npm audit security report ===


                             Manual Review
         Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

      Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance




Low             Prototype Pollution

  Package         yargs-parser

  Patched in      >=13.1.2 <14.0.0 || >=15.0.1 <16.0.0 || >=18.1.2

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > yargs > yargs-parser

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1500

found 1 low severity vulnerability in 1618 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

These low-security vulnerabilities shouldn't be blocking you, it's somewhat "normal" in the npm ecosystem. This is not a real “vulnerability” in the context of Create React App because it produces static bundles, but if you recover your dependencies it should go away.

```
npm --depth 999 update set-value && npm --depth 999 update mixin-deep
```